# Recommendation for logging hanging computer

Tags: windows, freeze

A customer of mine swears that my application causes his computer to freeze after some hours.

I watched my application carefully on his computer using TaskManager for hours, I tracked GDI resources, RAM usage and CPU.

Nothing obvious.

The customer allows me to debug his computer.

The EventViewer states:

Error: 04-19-2018 13:49:30 The system has been shutdown unexpectedly at 04-19-2018 00:27:04.

That's when the user noticed that the system didn't respond anymore and shut it down by long-pressing the On / Off button.

Before that, no critical errors were logged, only an event 264 warning 3 hours before the freeze.

Comment: Please add some more info on what sort of a freeze we're talking about here. Does anything still respond when "frozen"? Have you seen it happen or is it all hearsay? How do you recover from it (e.g. by long-pressing the power button and doing a hard reboot?)

Comment: @Mels Currently, still hearsay. Yes, long-pressing the power button. Will ask for further information.

Comment: @Mels The screen is still visible, touch-pressing or keyboard input isn't possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the System event log (see comments for how). Windows logs an entry there when restarting after an abnormal shutdown. If the system was able to log anything *during* (or just before) the crash, you'll find it in the vicinity of the abnormal shutdown entry.

If there's nothing helpful in the event logs that points to a software problem, my first suspect would be a temperature related hardware issue. It's pretty easy to check and rule out heavy dust buildup in the heatsinks preventing enough airflow.

Comment: How could I see if anything was written to the "System event log"?

Comment: Windows-key + R, type "eventvwr", OK gives you the Windows Event Viewer. You'll find the System log under "Windows Logs". Windows usually logs something there after recovering from an abnormal shutdown.

Comment: Or for a more end-user friendly way, just search the start menu for "event viewer" ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I'm in the eventviewer now. What would you recommend next? I see one entry "Critical->Source: Kernel-Power". Can I save all logs out so that I don't lose anything? Haven't found a way to do that yet.Edit: Got it, I right-click Windows Protocols and save each node. What would you do next, please?

Comment: What do those Kernel-Power events contain? What sort of events are logged right before the Kernel-Power one?

Comment: I have added the EventViewer screenshot. Is that where I need to look?

Comment: ps: Temperature isn't an issue. I monitored it, it's only around 60°C.